# Select the first child element from many div

Tags: css

How Can I select the first child element in this case below :

```
<div class="root">

  <div class="child">1</div> <---- i want this element

</div>
<div class="root">

  <div class="child">2</div> 

</div>
<div class="root">

  <div class="child">3</div> 

</div>
```

i try the css below but i select all `child` elements

```
.child:first-child {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want this just to affect the first root then you would also add a first-of-type to root

```
.root:first-of-type > .child:first-of-type {
   ...
}
```

Comment: check my update .. your solution will still work ? because i can have many other div in root

Comment: sorry man check again my update i want just the first child not all of them

Comment: Haha, Ok sorry, took me a while to understand what you meant. Edit 3 should be the final solution :)

Comment: i will open a new question